# PasswordHasher Always Fails Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm implementing a policy where passwords cannot be reused and have the structure in place, however I'm trying to work out how to check this against the PasswordHasher, I always get a failed match.
Please help on this..

```
        try
        {
            UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
            ApplicationUser cUser = await store.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
            if (cUser == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "User ID is not correct, please check and try again.");
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            else
            {
                /// Need to check the new password is already entered recently
                DataController dataController = new DataController();

                string[] pwds = dataController.CheckIfNewPasswordSameAsLastFivePassword(model.UserName);

                if (pwds != null)
                {
                    foreach (string pwd in pwds)
                    {
                        PasswordVerificationResult result1 = UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(pwd, model.UserIdentifier);

                        if (result1 == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please choose a password that you have not used before");
                            return BadRequest(ModelState);
                        }
                    }

                }
                //Send new password in model.UserIdentifier
                await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(cUser, UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(model.UserIdentifier));
                await store.UpdateAsync(cUser);
                ApplicationUser userdetails = new ApplicationUser();

                userdetails = dataController.GetUsersDetails(model.UserName);
                if (userdetails.Email != null)
                {
                    await ResetORForgotPasswordSendEmail(userdetails.FirstName, userdetails.UserName, userdetails.Email);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`VerifyHashedPassword` is going to compare the password with the user's *current* password. What you should be doing instead is simply hash the new password and do a simple string compare to your list of old password hashes:

```
if (pwds.Contains(UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(model.NewPassword)))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("NewPassword", "You've used that password before.");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this can work.  Proper password hashing requires using a salt.  The only way you can check whether a password was used before is to hash the current password in combination with the previous salts.  I can't see that happening here, but I have no idea what is under the hood for UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword( ).  For example, if they always use the same salt for a given user (bad security practice), then maybe it would work but I do not know if that is the case.